# How to take and output documents from a MongoDB database with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express

I've been working on one of my first API projects with NodeJS, Express and MongoDB. I can save new documents into the database with collection.insertOne(newDocument) method but I can not take existing documents and output them using collection.find({}).

Can you please help me:')

```
export const visualizeUser = (req, res) => {
    console.log("you are searching the user with username " + req.body.username);

    users.find({username: 'yavuz'}, (err, data) => {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log(data);
    });
}
```

thats the code I have written.

MongoInvalidArgumentError: Argument "options" must not be function

and that is the error I am getting.

Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Like error message is saying, you cannot pass function as options argument.

Look here: [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find)

Your code should look like this:

```
const visualizeUser = async (req, res) => {
try{
  console.log("you are searching the user with username " + 
  req.body.username);

  let data = await users.find({username: 'yavuz'});
  console.log(data)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. You know I accually just found it myself and came here to write for others but I saw you already did:)